# Virtualizing Windows with VT-d to play within it

Tags: linux, graphics-card, virtualization

I would like to know if what I want to is possible.
First, here is my hardware configuration :

- MB : Gigabyte H77-DS3H
- Intel Core i5 3330 (3.00GHz)
- MSI Nvidia GTX 760
- 8 Gb RAM 1333 MHz

What I want to do is to have a linux (probably ArchLinux) as a main and unique OS on my computer (I don't want a dualboot). And virtualizing Windows under Linux. I've read about VT-d (supported by my CPU) and PCIBackHide.

I'd like to know if I can initialize Linux with the Integrated Graphics and Virtualize Windows to use the GTX 760.

If I can do it, where do I have to plug my two screens ? On the MainBoard or the GTX 760 ?
How do I achive that idea ?

Comment: You're not going to have a good time playing 3D games inside a virtual machine as there will be a _ton_ of overhead involved. You're limited to the capabilities of the virtualization software itself.

Comment: That's why I try to bypass it with PCIBackHide, to pass the GTX 760 directly to the VM, without any emulator layer. I've seen videos of people playing inside VM using this. (This is what VT-d does)

Comment: What software are you using for virtualization? VirtualBox? Xen? And I'm assuming you've already tried following the normal procedure for "adding" a device to VirtualBox/Xen's list of devices that are to be passed-through? Why didn't that work?